# Extended validation certificate not changing browser bar green in Firefox

Tags: https, security-certificate, firefox, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some problems with an Extended validation certificate on a site that isn't showing the green bar correctly in Firefox. Chrome and IE are working fine.

When I load the page the bar appears for a few seconds and then disappears when the page has fully loaded.

Someone mentioned it could be because of loading images over HTTPS, but I'm not sure how valid this case is. We have one image on the page that is loaded from another source over HTTPS, the rest of the images are stored in the file system on the server.

**FYI** - its Windows Server 2008 and ASP.net

UPDATE: Solved this problem - the style sheet was loading in a Google Font url using http, not https - changed it and now it's working.

Comment: Can we have the url to make our own test?

Comment: Solved (update in question)

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem has solved but adding few lines that can help other people to understand this issue in details.

If your SSL certificate installed correctly and working on one or other browsers, in most of the cases, the issue behind not working on specific browser is from your programming side.

I found many website owner complaining about design related issue the found after installing SSL !! please make sure your CSS and other important file should call correctly. As SSL will hardly affect this portion.

I am sure it will help !!